# Android SQLite Database, creating the database and DDMS perspective

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

For my internship I'm working on an Android application, and trying to get a local database running to set up for offline referal as well as preventing new BasicAuth requests and a required database pull every time the user returns to a certain activity. To achieve this, I'm trying to set up a SQLite database, but things are not really working out.

I'm currently using [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) tutorial to try and set up the database. For my application specifically I edited the MySQLiteHelper and TicketsDataSource classes.

MySQLiteHelper:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TABLE_TICKETS = "tickets";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TICKET_ID = "ticketId";
public static final String COLUMN_TICKET_TITLE = "ticketTitle";
public static final String COLUMN_PROJECT_NAME = "projectName";
public static final String COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME = "clientName";
public static final String COLUMN_TICKET_DESCRIPTION = "ticketDescription";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database creation SQL statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_TICKETS 
      + "(" 
      + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
      + COLUMN_TICKET_ID + " text not null, " 
      + COLUMN_TICKET_TITLE+ " text not null, " 
      + COLUMN_PROJECT_NAME+ " text not null, " 
      + COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME+ " text not null, " 
      + COLUMN_TICKET_DESCRIPTION+ " text not null);";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
  database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
    "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TICKETS);
  onCreate(db);
}
}
```

TicketsDataSource:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class TicketsDataSource {

  // Database fields
  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
  private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
      MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TICKET_ID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TICKET_TITLE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PROJECT_NAME,
      MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TICKET_DESCRIPTION};

  public TicketsDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
  }

  public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
  }

  public Ticket createTicket(String ticket) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TICKET_DESCRIPTION, ticket);
    long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_TICKETS, null,
    values);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_TICKETS,
    allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
    null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Ticket newTicket = cursorToTicket(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newTicket;
  }

  public void deleteTicket(Ticket ticket) {
    long id = ticket.getId();
    System.out.println("Ticket deleted with id: " + id);
    database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_TICKETS, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
        + " = " + id, null);
  }

  public List<Ticket> getAllTickets() {
    List<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_TICKETS,
        allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      Ticket ticket = cursorToTicket(cursor);
      tickets.add(ticket);
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return tickets;
  }

  private Ticket cursorToTicket(Cursor cursor) {
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    ticket.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    ticket.setTicketId(cursor.getLong(1));
    ticket.setTicketTitle(cursor.getString(2));
    ticket.setClientName(cursor.getString(3));
    ticket.setProjectName(cursor.getString(4));
    ticket.setTicketDescription(cursor.getString(5));
    return ticket;
  }
}
```

In my activity, I then call the TicketsDataSource class by first defining it:

```
private TicketsDataSource datasource;
```

And then calling it from an if-statement that checks if the server has been called succesfully already:

```
else {
 datasource = new TicketsDataSource(this);
 datasource.open();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I switch to the DDMS view, I can't see any database being created after I run the application multiple times. In fact, I can't even see any other folders within the main "data" folder in the DDMS view. I'm not getting any error messages (except for an 'eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented', which seems to be irrelevant after some searching on google) at this moment, but when I place a system print in the onCreate function of the MySQLiteHelper class, it does not print anything in the log (it does appear in the else-statement). I'm not sure if my Java-code is faulty, or if there's something wrong with my general setup.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Dennis

Comment: To clarify, I can't find the folder /data/data/com.reflexionsdev.metaandroid using the adb shell command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll only be able to see files/folders in the /data folder if you're 
a: using the emulator, or 
b: using a rooted phone. Those are protected folders and can't be viewed by mere mortals.

The real test of what you've written is this - can you write to and read from the database?

Comment: I was assuming that the folders would pop up when a database was created, which I now see was a pretty dumb thing to do. I tried to interact with the database but was not succesful thus far, leading me to assume that something was wrong with the way I set up the database. Also, as I later on mentioned in a comment on my question, there seems to be no folder with my package name created in the /data/data folder, checking it using the adb shell command. I am working with the Genymotion emulator through Virtualbox btw, which might make things more complicated.

Comment: I will try getting reading and writing working, but the log not echo'ing something from the onCreate() function in the MySQLiteHelper class makes me believe the database is not created.
Thank you for your suggestion thus far btw

Answer (score 0):

The best android db troubleshooting solution for me was to add this method to my SQliteHelper class which will copy your sqlite db to the sd card on the device your testing on.  You can then open it up using any number of sqlite manager desktop apps and verify your tables and data.  You don't need to root the phone this way. While developing, I stick calls to this method where i need to get a snapshot of the db:

```
 public static void backup() {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//com.example//databases//" + DATABASE_NAME;
                String backupDBPath = DATABASE_VERSION + DATABASE_NAME;
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, "//Download//" + backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

you need to add external storage permissions to your manifest.